# Weird Indexing by Python and Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a variable X, it contains a list (Python list), of 10 Numpy 1-D arrays (basically vectors).
If I ask for X[100], it throws an error saying: IndexError: list index out of range

Which makes total sense, but, when I ask for X[:100], it doesn't throw an error and it returns the entire list! 
Why is that?

Comment: first one is indexing, another is slicing... slicing does not raise error.

Answer (score 1):

`X[:100]` means slice `X` from 0 to 100 or the end (whichever comes first)
But `X[100]` means the 100th element of `X`, and if it doesn't exist it throws an `index out of range` error